# How to project a cube onto another cube in vertex shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl

There was a unit cube black box in the figure[image]

in my scene which represent a coordinates range from -0.5 to 0.5 in X/Y/Z dimension. Now another cube would be added into the scene.  This cube could be any size. Now I want to project the cube onto the unit cube. The cyan polygons in the figure are the projection results I want.

I cut out the part out of range in the fragment shader:

`if (loc.x<-0.5 || loc.x>0.5 || loc.y<-0.5 || loc.y>0.5 || loc.z<-0.5 || loc.z>0.5) discard;`

But the result shows only two isolated faces, I want a polyhedron with 6 faces. How to generate this kind of polyhedron? Is it possible to calculate the 8 intersection points in vertex shader?

The following vertex shader is what I've tried right now but I cannot get what I want with this.

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 Pos; // vertex coord
uniform mat4 MVP; // translate & rotate

void main(void)
{
    vec4 loc = vec4(Pos, 1.0)*MVP; // after applying MVP

    vec3 center = vec3(MVP[0][3], MVP[1][3], MVP[2][3]); //EXTRACT translate part

    float r[5];
    if (loc[0] > 0)
    {
        r[0] = (0.5 - center[0]) / (loc[0] - center[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        r[0] = (-0.5 - center[0]) / (loc[0] - center[0]);
    }

    r[1] = (0.5 - center[1]) / (loc[1] - center[1]);
    r[2] = (-0.5 - center[1]) / (loc[1] - center[1]);
    r[3] = (0.5 - center[2]) / (loc[2] - center[2]);
    r[4] = (-0.5 - center[2]) / (loc[2] - center[2]);

    float tmp = 10;  // a big enough ratio
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (r[i] > 0 && tmp > r[i])
        {
            tmp = r[i];
        }
    }

    gl_Position = vec4(tmp*(loc[0] - center[0]) + center[0], tmp*(loc[1] - center[1]) + center[1],tmp*(loc[2] - center[2]) + center[2], 1) * MVP;
}
```

Comment: which programming laguage are You using?

Comment: @YeshwinVermaTheProgrammer glsl is a programming language: [OpenGL Shading Language (GLSL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to clip the cube against the outer cube? The regular clipping method also used by the GPU should work for that.

Comment: Seems that the number of faces would change according to the MVP.

Comment: @BDL I‘ve tried to clip the outer parts using `discard` but this produce some isolated faces. If you know some other techs, could you give me some details? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @yj_zhou: I'm not sure if it is possible to implement this in a vertex shader. Depending on the placement of the cubes, the result might have more than four corners (happens when a corner of the border is inside the cube).  You can't generate additional edges/vertices inside a vertex shader. In addition, you need information about the connectivity of the vertices (edges) to which you also don't have access in the VS.

Comment: @BDL If cannot, how to implement this?